# HIGHCHARTS Areaspline Dynamic data graph gives poor result

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Am trying to create a Dynamic Areaspline graph. But is results that the graph shows in a strange way. Is there any idea to get a series without any disturbance. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/mchc59nb/1/

```
    chart: {
                    type: 'areaspline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,
                    events: {
                        load: function () {

                            // set up the updating of the chart each second
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function () {
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                    y = Math.random();
                                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                },

 series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                type: 'areaspline',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
```

Comment: It is a bug. Use 5.0.3/the latest github version or disable animation. http://jsfiddle.net/mchc59nb/5/

Comment: @morganfree Thanks for the solution. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a bug again. what you see is related to the spline calculation in the middle of the transition. You can get better results if you would just use "spline" or "area" as the series type, or switch animation off for now.